# Solr-ish Query API on top of relational database

Tags: mysql, api, solr

I have a data source which is sitting in relational database. I managed to index/store everything into Solr and thrilled to see the search performance and the awesome API (search/admin..etc).

However, people say if your data is truly structured, relational database should be fast if you index everything. However, even if I dump all the data into a relation database like MySQL, what I am missing is all the beautiful query API.

I guess my question is:

1. is it possible to only use the query API of Solr-ish and totally use relation database as the backend instead of using index at all.
2. if that is not possible, is there any mature project/product that can build a full stack query API on a relational database?

Answer (score 0):

Document search engines and relational databases serves different usage patterns. If you're using Solr for anything that involves tokenization and analysis chains, replicating that in an RDBMS requires implementing that functionality yourself (or just using a subset, such as full text indices in certain RDBMSes). I detailed some of these differences and features in [Should I just query the database or use a proper search engine solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098448/should-i-just-query-the-database-or-use-a-proper-search-engine-solution/25099102#25099102).

It's usually better to use the RDBMS as the main storage for your data and then push it into the search index as required. This will also let you get new features from those who care about search and the problem it tries to solve, without having to wait for a niche product to implement it on top of your RDBMS (there's still quite a few new features in each iteration of Lucene, Elastic and solr).